# Let $A, B, C, D ⊆ U$. Prove $(A⊆B)∧(C⊆D)∧(B∩D=∅)⇒A∩C=∅$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The topic touches on set theory and proofs.
I understand that $A, B, C$ and $D$ are subsets of $U$. From my understanding, a subset is a set that is equal to the original powerset

My approach was:

1. Let there be an element $x$ that belongs to $A$. Since $A\subseteq U$, that means $x$ also belongs to $U$. And since $B\subseteq U$, that means the element $x\in U$ also belongs to $B$, thus $A \subseteq B$
2. Let there be an element $x$ that belongs to $C$. Since $C \subseteq U$, that means $x$ also belongs to $U$. And since $D\subseteq U$, that means the element $x$ in $U$ also belongs to $D$, thus $C \subseteq D$

But, I don't really know how to approach the last 2 conditions:
"$B\cap D = \varnothing$ and $A\cap C = \varnothing$.

Comment: See if you can prove $(A\cap C) \subseteq (B\cap D)$.

Comment: You seem to be very confused about subsets, to the point that "a subset is a set that is equal to the original powerset" is indecipherable (other than "original", all the terms have formal meaning, but if I take it literally, you're very wrong).  Feel free to read the answers below, but I would _strongly_ recommend you review what a "subset" is (and if it's in your text, what a "powerset" is too, to contrast their meaning)

Comment: Your 1. is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore $U$.  It need never come into play.  You can also prove this directly, rather than by contradiction.

Let $x \in A$.  Then because $A \subseteq B$, we also know that $x \in B$.  Since $B \cap D = \varnothing$, we know from $x \in B$ that $x \notin D$.  And since $C \subseteq D, x \notin D$ tells us that also $x \notin C$.

In short, if $x \in A$, we've shown that $x \notin C$.  That means no element can possibly be in both $A$ and $C$; in other words, $A \cap C = \varnothing.$

Answer (score 1):

A way I like to approach these (where you prove a set is empty) is via contradiction.

- Suppose $x \in A \cap C$ (so that $A \cap C$ is nonempty).
- Then $x \in A$ and $x \in C$. *(Definition of intersection.)*
- Then $x \in B$ and $x \in D$. *(Definition of subset.)*
- Then $x \in B \cap D$. *(Definition of intersection.)*

This contradicts that $B \cap D = \varnothing$, hence proving the claim.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very useful identity adequate to solve this exercise. Precisely speaking, given an universe set $U$ where $X\subseteq U$ and $Y\subseteq U$, it may be claimed that $X\subseteq Y$ iff $X\cap Y = X$. Based on it, we conclude the desired result:
\begin{align*}
A\cap C & = (A\cap B)\cap (C\cap D)\\\\
& = A\cap(B\cap(C\cap D))\\\\
& = A\cap(B\cap(D\cap C))\\\\
& = A\cap (B\cap D)\cap C\\\\
& = A\cap \varnothing\cap C = \varnothing
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!